# awk + adding a column with a value only if column 8 is greater than X + anomoly

Tags: awk

Here is my file:

```
$ cat -v test4
"Rec Open Date"|"MSISDN"|"IMEI"|"Data Volume (Bytes)"|"Device Manufacturer"|"Device Model"|"Product Description"|"Data_Volume_MB"
"2015-10-06"|"427"|"060"|"137765"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G900I"|"$39 Plan"|"0.131383"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"620"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"007"|"290"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"050"|"48836832"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)"|"Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"|"46.5744"
"2016-04-27"|"498"|"220"|"146610"|"Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd"|"OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,OPPO R6001,OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006"|"$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"|"0.139818"
"2015-10-06"|"409"|"720"|"113755347"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G360G"|"$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"|"108.486"
"2015-10-06"|"742"|"620"|"19840943"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone S (A1530)"|"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"|"18.9218"
"2015-10-06"|"387"|"180"|"0"|"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd"|"HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11"|"PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"|"0"
```

What I want to do is add a column at the end that has a value 1 if column $8 is greater than 20 else give it a value of zero. I think I have the command right but for some reason some numbers are not obeying the condition

this is the part that that I am having the issue but it is giving me this aniomoly:
`NR>1{n=$8; gsub(/"/,"",n); (n>20?$(NF+1)=1:$(NF+1)=0)}1'`
**Can anyone advise?**

For example:
when this condition `n>108?`column 8 = "108.486" column 9 equates to 1 and there are 2 others that should not equate to 1 `46.5744` and `18.9218`

```
$ awk -F'|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF+1)=q">200MB"q} NR>1{n=$8; gsub(/"/,"",n); (n>108?$(NF+1)=1:$(NF+1)=0)}1' OFS='|' test4 | awk -F'|' '{print $8 FS $9}'
"Data_Volume_MB"|">200MB"
"0.131383"|0
"0"|0
"0"|0
"46.5744"|1
"0.139818"|0
"108.486"|1
"18.9218"|1
"0"|0
```

but when its this condition `n>20?`column 8 = "108.486" column 9 equates to 0 but `46.5744` equates to 1

```
$ awk -F'|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF+1)=q">200MB"q} NR>1{n=$8; gsub(/"/,"",n); (n>20?$(NF+1)=1:$(NF+1)=0)}1' OFS='|' test4 | awk -F'|' '{print $8 FS $9}'
"Data_Volume_MB"|">200MB"
"0.131383"|0
"0"|0
"0"|0
"46.5744"|1
"0.139818"|0
"108.486"|0
"18.9218"|0
"0"|0
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `>20` case, observe that one small change fixes the problem:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF+1)=q">200MB"q} NR>1{n=$8; gsub(/"/,"",n); (n+0>20?$(NF+1)=1:$(NF+1)=0)}1' OFS='|' test4 | awk -F'|' '{print $8 FS $9}'
"Data_Volume_MB"|">200MB"
"0.131383"|0
"0"|0
"0"|0
"46.5744"|1
"0.139818"|0
"108.486"|1
"18.9218"|0
"0"|0
```

The change is replacing `n>20` with `n+0>20`.  The reason is that the `+0` forces awk to treat `n` as a number, not a string, and hence do *numeric* comparisons.

In other words, awk is capable of either string (alphanumeric) or arithmetic comparison.  It chooses between them based on context.  By adding `0` to `n`, we force it to use the arithmetic comparison.

#### Simplified example

This shows the difference between `$1>20` and `$1+0>20`:

```
$ echo '"108.486"' | awk '{gsub(/"/,"",$1); $(NF+1)=($1>20?1:0)} 1' OFS='|'
108.486|0
$ echo '"108.486"' | awk '{gsub(/"/,"",$1); $(NF+1)=($1+0>20?1:0)} 1' OFS='|'
108.486|1
```